# Adding all files in a Project Sub Folder to .gitignore File, but not the Sub Folder

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitignore

I have a Project folder named "**Project_A**", inside my project folder the sub folders are "**Sub_B**, **Sub_C**, **Sub_D**...etc", I need to exclude all files inside the **Sub_C** folder. For that, I have created the **.gitignore** file inside the **Project_A** folder with the bellow code inside the .gitignore file.

```
Porject_A/Sub_C/*
```

But when I pushed my project into bitbucket the **Sub_C** folder didn't upload into the remote repository. What I need is to exclude all files in the **Sub_C** , folder not the folder along. How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

After you *include* the `Sub_C` folder itself in your `.gitignore`, try *excluding* all the files in the `Sub_C` folder:

```
/*
!/Project_A
/Project_A/*
!/Project_A/Sub_C
/Project_A/Sub_C/*
```

Comment: Let me try your solution :)

Comment: Sorry, It didn't work for me...no change observed under the concerned branch in the remote repository .

Comment: @PraveenGeorge Can you try one more time.  If not, then I will delete it.